# How to Query Fields in a Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have a table in SQL Server that looks like this.

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to create SQL to loop through each source table, identify the relevant field, and perform counts, based on the field.  So, for instance, I want to look at the table named 'US_SCM' and the field named 'DESCR' and get a total count of all records.  Then, for this same table and field, count all nulls.  Then, for the same table and field, count all negative numbers.  Then, for this table and field, count all positive numbers, and so on and so forth.  Counting nulls, negatives, positives, etc., is simple enough, but I'm wondering how to write some code to loop through records in a table, and do all of these kinds of counts.  I can use SQL or VBA for the task.  I'm not sure what the dynamic SQL would look like, and it may be just too hard to do this kind of thing anyway, but I'm definitely open to ideas!  If I go down the VBA path, I think the code would look something like the sample below, but this needs some kind of embellishment, for sure!

```
Sub Download_Standard_BOM()
'Initializes variables
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

'Setup the connection string for accessing MS SQL database
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'For a trusted Connection, where your user ID has permissions on the SQL Server:
cnn.Open ConnectionString:="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
"Data Source=" & "Server_Name" & ";Initial Catalog=" & "DB_Name" & _
";TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES"

cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rRng = sht.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    i = 2
    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

        On Error Resume Next
        StrQuery = rCell.Value

            StrQuery = "Select COUNT(" & rCell.Offset(0, 1) & ")"
            StrQuery = StrQuery & "FROM " & rCell.Value & """"

                rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

            i = i + 1
            rst.Close
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Big thanks to all who look at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would query that table in your picture and bring it back as a recordset. Then iterate through the recordset and stitch together a second sql statement. Execute that second sql statement and grab the values that are returned, writing the results out to Sheet1 (or whatever).

this would look something like:

```
Sub Download_Standard_BOM()
    'Initializes variables
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst_tables As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rst_results as ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim StrQuery As String


    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long 

    'Setup the connection string for accessing MS SQL database
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    'For a trusted Connection, where your user ID has permissions on the SQL Server:
    cnn.Open ConnectionString:="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
    "Data Source=" & "Server_Name" & ";Initial Catalog=" & "DB_Name" & _
    ";TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES"

    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'we will be writing out to this lastrow
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  


    'Write a query to get this sql server table from your picture
    StrQuery = "Select * FROM theTableInYourPicture;"

    rst_tables.Open StrQuery, cnn

    'Check to make sure we got some database
    If rst_tables.EOF and rst_tables.BOF Then 
        msgbox("Couldn't retrieve any data from that table from your picture");
        exit sub
    End if

    'Still here? Lets loop through this recordset
    Do While Not rst_tables.eof

        tablename = rst_tables.Fields("Source_Table").value
        columnname = rst_tables.Fields("Source_Column_Name").value

        'write it out
        sht.cells(lastrow, 1).value = tablename
        sht.cells(lastrow, 2).value = columnname

        'Now set up some sql to get the values you want
        strSQL="SELECT "
        strSQL=strSQL & "   count(distinct " & columnName & ") as [Total Counts], "
        strSQL=strSQL & "   SUM(CASE WHEN " & columnName & " IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Nulls, "
        strSQL=strSQL & "   SUM(CASE WHEN " & columnName & " < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NegativeNumbers, "
        strSQL=strSQL & "   SUM(CASE WHEN " & columnName & " > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PositiveNumbers "
        strSQL=strSQL & "   SUM(CASE WHEN " & columnName & "=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ZERO "
        strSQL=strSQL & "FROM "
        strSQL=strSQL & "   " & tablename & ";"

        'got get it
        Set rst_results = New ADODB.Recordset
        rst_results.open strSQL, cnn

        'Did it return anything?
        if rst_results.eof and rst_results.eof Then
            'poop. got nothing
            sht.Cells(lastRow, 3).value = "NO RESULTS!"
        else
            'great! we got something. write it out
            sht.cells(lastRow, 3).copyFromREcordset rst_results
        End if

        'Close the recordset
        rst_results.close

        'increment the row to which we are writing
        lastRow = lastRow + 1

        'increment to the next table/record
        rst_tables.movenext
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I made a few small modifications to your code, and all is working well now!!  Thanks JNevill!!

Comment: Great to hear! I was hoping that it was workable with only a few modifications since I wrote it out without being able to debug.